# adding new rows using js but new row has input values from 1st row. how to change the input values to blank?

Tags: javascript

I created a table where the user can add additional rows when the click the "Add" button. It works great however it is copying the first row  values and I want the new row input values to be blank. So the user can start on a blank row.

Below is the code I am using.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
     <?php $tabindex = 10;

        $count  =1;
        for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
        ?>
        <tr>
                
                <td class="" id="tbl_id"><input id="make" type="text" name="make[]" autofocus placeholder="Make" tabindex="<?php echo $tabindex + 2; ?>" value = "<?php echo $_POST['make'][$x]; ?>" /></td>
             
            <td class=""><button class="btn btn-primary m-1" tabindex = "<?php echo $tabindex + 8; ?>" type="button" title = "Insert Row" value="Add Row" onclick="ob_adRows.addRow(this)">+</button></td
        </tr>
        <?php 
        $count += 1;    
        $tabindex = $count * 10;
        } ?>

<script>
function adRowsTable(id){
  var table = document.getElementById(id);
  var me = this;
  if(document.getElementById(id)){
    var row1 = table.rows[1].outerHTML;
      
      function tabindex_add(){
           var tabindex = 1;
          $('input,select').each(function() {
            if (this.type != "hidden") {
            var $input = $(this);
            $input.attr("tabindex", tabindex);
            tabindex++;
            }
        });
      }
          
      
    //adds index-id in cols with class .tbl_id
    function setIds(){
      var tbl_id = document.querySelectorAll('#'+ id +' .tbl_id');
     var input_model = document.querySelectorAll('#'+ id +' .model');
      for(var i=0; i<tbl_id.length; i++) 
      {
          tbl_id[i].innerHTML = i+1;
          //input_model[i].value = "MADE IT";
          
      }
                
    }

    //add row after clicked row; receives clicked button in row
    me.addRow = function(btn){
      btn ? btn.parentNode.parentNode.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', row1): 
       table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',row1);
      setIds();
     tabindex_add();
    }

    //delete clicked row; receives clicked button in row
    me.delRow = function(btn){
      btn.parentNode.parentNode.outerHTML ='';
      setIds();
    }
  }
}

//create object of adRowsTable(), pass the table id
var ob_adRows = new adRowsTable('table1');
</script>
```

Comment: If I understood the code, it looks like row1 is the copy of the existing row, then you use row1 to insert it after the clicked row.

Comment: Yup, correct, I want to keep the integrity of the second row when I create the new one. I could hard code it in the js but was wondering if there is an easier way to just clear the value contents or row1 before adding the new row in.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the code to add a row with empty cells

Answer (score 0):

Yuu are setting the variable `row1` this way: `var row1 = table.rows[1].outerHTML;`
By using the `outerHTML` property and assigning its return value to `row1`, you are making a copy of the second row in the table. For example:

```
 <table id="table" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
  console.log(document.getElementById("table").rows[1].outerHTML)
</script>
```

Will return:

```
"&lt;tr&gt;
    &lt;td&gt;Bill&lt;/td&gt;
    &lt;td&gt;Smith&lt;/td&gt;
    &lt;td&gt;23&lt;/td&gt;
  &lt;/tr&gt;"
```

In the `me.addRow` function you are then inserting `row1`, which is has the content you assigned in `var row1 = table.rows[1].outerHTML;`.

If you just want to insert an empty row, you could for example do this:

```
  let row1 = document.createElement('tr');
  let columns = 3;
  for(let i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    let cell = document.createElement('td');
    row1.appendChild(cell);
  }
```

This way variable `row1` will contain a `<tr>` HTML element with empty cells. The number of cells is specified in the `columns` variable.